# Usage of prototype in Javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm confused where should I use prototype to declare a method ? What I read is, if I create a method that is declared by prototype, all instances are using same reference so is it static or something different ? Because I can reach instance properties in a prototype method ? But in c#, you cannot reach class variables(not static) in static methods?

An Example:

```
function Calculator()
{
     if(this === window){
          return new Calculator();
     }

     this.Bar = "Instance Variable";
}

Calculator.prototype.SaySomething = function(thing){
     return thing + " " + Bar;
}


Calculator().SaySomething("Test"); // Test Instance Variable
```

Comment: JavaScript has an object system very different from that of other object oriented languages. For a introduction to JS and inheritance, read: http://phrogz.net/JS/classes/OOPinJS2.html Edit: Also read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_Revisited
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Comment: in your prototype function u have a slight mistake (this.Bar) instead of Bar

Comment: @rx80 links are so good. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you read [JS The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742) by Douglas Crockford.  It will give you a better understanding of JS's prototypal object model.

Answer (score 2):

`prototype`'s work in conjunction with the `new` keyword.  Take the following example:

```
function Calculator(bar) {
     this.Bar = bar;
}

Calculator.prototype.SaySomething = function(thing){
     return thing + " " + this.Bar;
}

var calInstance = new Calendar("Instance Variable");
calInstance.SaySomething("Test");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correctly declaring the prototyped method, but incorrectly calling it. `Calculator` is not a static object, just a class, and so you can only call it's methods when you've created an instance of the object.

```
var calc = new Calculator();
calc.SaySomething('thing');
//this would return "thing Instance Variable"
```

In short, Javascript does not use class and instance methods, just instance methods.